# Prevent listening events on certain DOM elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, xbl, web-component, shadow-dom

Besides the new Shadow Dom and the old HTML iframe element, is there a way to prevent users from listening for *[delegated]* events on DOM elements inside my widget?

P.S. I heard Firefox had XBL which has features similar to Shadow DOM. Is it currently supported?

Answer (score 1):

[Read](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) how delegating event handling works.

So, I don't think that it's possible. Until you block event propagating on root level (e.g. `document`).
Or you can override `(HTMLElement||Element).prototype.addEventListener` method.

But why do you need it?

Comment: I need it to encapsulate my DOM API. Blocking propagation on document will break the web-app. As for overriding, simple `delete HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener` would restore the native method.

Comment: Right now reading about "Shadow DOM" =) isn't it enough encapsulated?

Comment: It's not enough encapsulated in browsers that don't support it :)

Comment: Nhah =D I think you care too much. Overcare =)

Comment: As far as I understand, Polymer's Shadow DOM shim is just a compatibility layer, it doesn't do the actual encapsulating. I would be happy if proved wrong.

Comment: @katspaugh even the native implementation of Shadow DOM is not security-encapsulated - you can always gain access to the contained shadow nodes via the `shadowRoot` property. Shadow DOM hasn't had a goal of security encapsulating its contents since early in 2012. *(Note: I'm a contributor to the Web Components working group)*

Comment: @csuwldcat, that's news to me. If you post it as an answer, I would accept it, because this changes the whole perspective.

Comment: Huh, right now you can just delete the `shadowRoot` property. http://jsbin.com/EyuYeba/2/edit?js,output